# I want to list out elements from a JSON data...but iam unable to fetch those child elements

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'v copied the child elements directly into my emp.json file and im able to list out the elements, but i don know how to run three nested loop to fetch the child elements.
I want Name, Limit & tax-type from details`

I'v tried with the child array...

**index.html file**

```
<body>
    <ul id= "details"></ul>
    <script>

       ` var dat = new XMLHttpRequest();`
        `dat.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var response = JSON.parse(dat.responseText);
            var details = response.details;

            var output = ' ';`

            `for(var i=0;i<details.length; i++){
                output = output+'<li>' +details[i].name+ '</li>';
                output = output+'<li>' +details[i].limit+ '</li>';
                output = output+'<li>' +details[i].tax_type+ '</li>';
            }
            document.getElementById('details').innerHTML= output;
    }
};
          dat.open("GET", "emp.json", true);
          dat.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It will be helpful if we can list these elements into table.

Comment: Could you please sample JSON response from emp.json?

Comment: {
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Manage Tax Lists",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "parent_sec_no": "form_vi_a",
                "parent_name": "Chapter VI A",
                "parent_order": 1
            },
            "detail": [
                {
                    "sec_no": "80C",
                    "sec_name": "Part-II Investment U/s Sec 80C can be made upto Rs. 1.5 Lac together",
                    "details": [
                        {

Comment: "details": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "name": "Housing. Loan [Principal Repayment]",
                            "limit": 150000,
                            "tax_type": 11
                     }

Comment: Please add the entire json,   I can't see the details array

Comment: "details": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "name": "Housing. Loan [Principal Repayment]",
                            "limit": 150000,
                            "tax_type": 11
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Unit Linked Plan [ ULIP ]",
                            "limit": 150000,
                            "tax_type": 4
                        },

Answer (score 0):

```js
var responseData = `{ 
   "status":"success",
   "message":"Manage Tax Lists",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "_id":{  
            "parent_sec_no":"form_vi_a",
            "parent_name":"Chapter VI A",
            "parent_order":1
         },
         "detail":[  
            {  
               "sec_no":"80C",
               "sec_name":"Part-II Investment U/s Sec 80C can be made upto Rs. 1.5 Lac together",
               "details":[  
                  {  
                     "id":11,
                     "name":"Housing. Loan [Principal Repayment]",
                     "limit":150000,
                     "tax_type":11
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`;

function getDetails(textData) {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(textData);
  var data = jsonData.data;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].detail.length; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < data[i].detail[j].details.length; k++) {
        console.log('name:' + data[i].detail[j].details[k].name + ' - limit:' + data[i].detail[j].details[k].limit + ' - tax_Type:' + data[i].detail[j].details[k].tax_type);
      }
}

getDetails(responseData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code write the json to a table

```
<body>
    <table>
     <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>name</th>
       <th>limit</th> 
       <th>tax-type</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="details">

     </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>

       var dat = new XMLHttpRequest();
        dat.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = jsonData.data;
            var response = JSON.parse(dat.responseText);
            var data= response.data;

             var output = ''
             data.forEach(a=>{
                a.detail.forEach(b=>{
                   b.details.forReach(val =>{
                          ouptut += `<tr><td>${val.name}</td><td>${val.limit}</td><td>${val.tax_type}</td></tr>`;
                          )}
                })
             })

            document.getElementById('details').innerHTML= output;
    }
};
          dat.open("GET", "emp.json", true);
          dat.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```